# DataGrid not displaying data

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

I am trying to display a `DataGrid` on my mobile application after reading a CSV file and processing it. Here is what I have so far:

```
private void btOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {           
        // Process all data into an array of Object 
        // this.records array contains objects of type MyRecord

        // Create datatable and define columns
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("myDt");
        dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn("String A",typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn("Int 1", typeof(int)));                   

        // Loop through and create rows
        foreach(MyRecord record in records) {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();                        
            row[0] = record.stringA;
            row[1] = record.int1;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }   

        // Create dataset and assign it to the datasource..
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("myDs");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);                                          
        dataGrid.DataSource = ds;
        dataGrid.Refresh();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message,"Error");
    }
}
```

All I get is a blank data grid component when running my application. Can somebody point out my mistake? or how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without DataSet
dataGrid.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Thanks.. simply this worked. But I do see examples show using dataset. Any reasoning why it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it would help...

```
DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

Ds.Tables.Add(Dt);
Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("String A", typeof(string)));                
Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Int 1", typeof(int)));      

Dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Patricia", 3 });
Dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 4 });
Dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mayer", 5 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = ds;         
dataGrid.Refresh();
```

Try:

```
dataGrid.SetDataBinding(ds, "myDt");
```

This has the effect of setting the datasource and datamember at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is You cannot refer the datasource to only as Dataset it should be something like Dataset.Datatable...
Here it is an example

```
Dataset DS = new Dataset();
DS.Tables.Add(TableName);

//
Populate dataset
//

mydatagrid.Datasource = DS.Tables[0];
```

So in short you have to refer to the table within the dataset to display the Data...
Hope this Helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work as well if you set the DataSource to the table inside the DataSet as well .. something like:

```
datagrid.DataSource = ds.Tables["myDt"];
```

Remember that a dataset could contain more than one table and we have to tell it explicitly which one to use or where to look :)

hth

Answer (score -1):

I know its very late to answer....But it will be helpful to others...

```
DataSet ds = gridUpdate.GridUpdate();
```

(dont worry about gridUpdate.GridUpdate()its my function to Create dataset)

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]
```